# Determining the voltage labeled Vx by Nodal Analysis [Voltage Controlled Current Source]

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

How to find the voltage labeled v(x) by Nodal Analysis?

[image]

The sum of currents from node 2 to node 0 is equal to 0. However, I do not know the the current of 0.1Vx. How to solve the question?

**Thank you for your help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is voltage controlled current source, the current from node 0 to 2 is 0.1V<sub>x</sub>. Here replace V<sub>x</sub> = V2-V3. So the last equation is :

$$ (V_2-V_1)/2 + (V_2-V_3)/4 - 0.1V_x =0 $$
$$ =>(V_2-V_1)/2 + (V_2-V_3)/4 - 0.1(V_2-V_3)=0 $$

Solving this equation, you would get V2, since V1=50V & V3 =100V

Comment: 0.1Vx is a current instead of a voltage?

Comment: yup.It is a dependent current source, whose value is dependent on voltage Vx. Search with "voltage controlled current source" for more details.

Comment: So the answer should be V2 = 61.54V and Vx = -38.46V. Right? Are there any other methods for me to check the real answer by myself?

Comment: There are other techniques like mesh analysis, superposition theorem. You can apply them and verify your answer. By normal inspection you can also tell if the values make any sense.